# Confused if it is right to use my class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, nsobject

Can anyone walk me through the process of my project. I had too much tutorials and I'm not really sure anymore which route to take. So I have two `UITextField`s that will accept a string. These are as follows:

```
UITextField *fruitNameField;
UITextField *fruitDescriptionField;
```

Inside my `ViewController`, the code goes like this

```
NSString *fruitName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[fruitNameField text]];
NSString *fruitDescription = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[fruitDescriptionField text]];
NSLog(@"Fruit: %@, Description: %@", fruitName, fruitDescription);
```

As you can see above, it is not using my `Fruit` class.

So here's my `Fruit` implementation

```
- (id)init
{
    return [self initWithName:@"N/A"
                  description:@"N/A"
                     priority:2];
}

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name description:(NSString *)desc priority:(int)prio
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setFruitName:name];
        [self setFruitDescription:desc];
        [self setFruitPriority:prio];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Description

- (NSString *)description
{
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"[%d] %@: %@", fruitPriority, fruitName, fruitDescription];
}
```

The question is, do I need to use the `Fruit` class I created whenever I input a string from my `ViewController` or not?

This is my `ViewController` by the way

```
- (IBAction)writeToPlist:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"writeToPlist");

    NSString *fruitName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[fruitNameField text]];
    NSString *fruitDescription = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[fruitDescriptionField text]];

    NSDictionary *fruitDetail = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fruitName, fruitDescription, nil]
                                                            forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Fruit", @"Description", nil]];

    NSMutableArray *fruitPlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self filePath]];

    if (fruitPlist == nil) {
        fruitPlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *fruitDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [fruitDictionary setObject:fruitDetail forKey:fruitName];

    [fruitPlist addObject:fruitDictionary];
    [fruitPlist writeToFile:[self filePath] atomically:YES];

    [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                        completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Your `Fruit` class looks good to me, so what is it you want to know?

Comment: How are you using your Fruit class in your ViewController implementation?

Comment: Your question is unclear. **Please clarify what you're actually asking**.

Comment: Sorry for your confusion. I will edit the question.

Comment: @Puneet that's the problem, I'm not really sure how to use it inside my `ViewController`.

Comment: No you dont need Fruit class if you just want to create a Plist out of the values you are entering in the textfields. Please explain why do you think of using Fruit class in first place? Do you have anything else in your mind apart from creating .pList file from values entered by user from UI?

Comment: No nothing, just add the strings to a `plist` and display it in a `tableview`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your Fruit class. It is a wrapper around a simple data structure, which could also be contained in a NSDictionary, but I think it is a good habit to try to create concrete objects in one's code. If you do not exaggerate it it can make code more readable.

Try to cut down on your code. It does not have to be this verbose. Also, I think you want a simple array of fruit dictionaries in your plist, not nested dictionaries.

```
-(void)writeToPlist {
  NSArray *fruits = @[@{
                       @"name":nameTextField.text,
                       @"desc":descriptionTextField.text }];
  [fruits writeToFile:[self filePath] atomically:YES];
}
```

Note that this does not use your fruit class. You go straight from the text fields to the plist, so there is no need. You could also write a method that writes a fruit to a plist.

```
-(void)writeToPlist:(Fruit*)fruit {
  NSArray *fruits = @[ @{ @"name":fruit.name, @"desc":fruit.desc } ];
  [fruits writeToFile:[self filePath] atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: So am I on the right path not using my `Fruit` class the strings to a plist?

Comment: What about the above is not clear?

Comment: It is, I'm just really confused.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how will I access the dictionary `key` where my array is?

Answer (score 0):

UITextField is a subclass of UIView so you should override the method

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
```

and not

```
- (id)init
```

I see an IBAction... is your UITextField initialized by a nib file?

in this case you have to override the method awakeFromNib in this way:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    [super awakeFromNib];

    // customization here
}
```

or in or after the viewDidLoad callback in the viewcontroller that own the views, setup your textField

Comment: Idk, sorry. I didn't downvote it.

Comment: have you tried? because for UIView the default initializer is initWithFrame and not init